# Google Pub/Sub modifyAckDeadLine duplicates

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

quick question here, we're seeing that if we NACK a message ( modifyAckDeadline(0) ) the message duplicates and it's sent to the front of the queue that's great, but should we also have to acknowledge that message after the NACK?, we ask because we have in the subscription exponential back-off enabled 0-600 seconds, and we're seeing a lot of duplicates for a couple of messages ie: 10 messages stack up to 200 messages after 10 minutes. So we think that the original message stays always until max retries of exponential back-off is reached multiplied by the times of NACKs for a message.

If we're right the solution is simple NACK -> then ACK the original message or ACK then NACK

Acknowledgement deadline = 600 seconds

Ordering key enabled

[image]

Comment: A message is a message. If it's NACK it stays in the queue, if it's ACK it disappear. There isn't duplication. Your issue is somewhere else!

Comment: Yes i think the same is something that we can't see, forgot to mention *edited the original question, ordering key is enabled, i don't know if for example i have 10 messages in the same ordering key and i NACK the first message then the whole 10 message are queue up again giving a total of 20 messages? just asking for better understanding the only thing that the code does is listen for new message try to process if it can't process then NACK ( modifyAckDeadline(0) )

Comment: The ordering key don't change the behavior. Where do you see the message stack up into the subscription? Into a graph? A Cloud Monitoring metrics? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Yes sure post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ordering keys, if you receive multiple messages for the same ordering key and nack the first message, then all messages already received for that ordering key will be redelivered, even if you ack them. Messages are can be sent to the client in batches and therefore, if you nack one of them, the subsequent messages may already be queued up for delivery in the client and get delivered to your callback. However, even if you ack these messages, they will be redelivered.

So for example, let's say you have a single key "A" and messages 1, 2, and 3 are sent as a batch to the client. You receive 1 in your callback and nack it, then receive 2 and ack it, then receive 3 and ack it. After the backloff period has passed for message 1, you will receive messages 1, 2, and 3 again. Whenever a message is redelivered, you should ack the redelivery (either process it again or realize you've already processed it and only ack it).

This is called the "consistent redelivery" property, which you can read about in the "Ordering Properties" section of the [Medium post about ordering keys](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-pub-sub-ordered-delivery-1e4181f60bc8).

Comment: Thanks, so there is nothing wrong in our code, is just a normal behaviour  when using ordering keys!. Well in this case our country fiscal tax invoices webservices went down and all of our transactions start to being queued up, that explains why with the ordering key all the invoices for a client were exponentially duplicated until they pass